# Fundamental knowledge about invest, stock and economics for self learning

Tags: macroeconomics, microeconomics, mathematical-economics, stock-market, financial-economics

I am not expertised in the field of economics and stock so I do not know anything about invest. Would anyone please recommend any book/textbook for the initial leaner to get understanding of all these knowledge?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: personal investment questions belong to personal finance & money stack